# LDAP connecting to DC

Tags: ldap

Our network has suffered from years of neglect and improper configuration.
I am finding that, using Wireshark, our LDAP operations are severely slowed and sometimes halted by it trying to connect to old DC's that have been relieved of DC duty a couple years ago but still exist keeping the same name and ip.

Any ideas on where to look/how to stop our network from apparently seeing those as DC's?

Comment: What kind of LDAP are you using, OpenLDAP, or does the DC here signify Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

There is a knowledge base article from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555846/en-us

If the LDAP Server doesn't read out the DCs from the AD itself, you will need to look into your LDAP Server configuration. (as you surely know)